# Calculating DCT in reversed vector

Tags: fourier-transform, dct, inverse

I'm doing an exercise in which I need to show that the DCT of $\tilde{x} = (x_{N-1}, x_{N-2}, ..., x_1, x_0) $, with $\tilde x_m = x_{N-m-1}$, is equal to $ \tilde{X}_k = (-1)^{k}X_{k}$, but I have difficulty with the indices in the cosine manipulation and $\tilde x$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \tilde X_k &=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\tilde x_{m}\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k(N-m-1+\frac{1}{2})}{N}\bigg) \\ 
  &=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\tilde x_{m} \cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k(N-m-\frac{1}{2})}{N}\bigg) \\
 &=& \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\tilde x_m \cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k(-m-\frac{1}{2})}{N} + \pi k \bigg) \\
 &=&\sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\tilde x_m \cos\bigg(\pi k - \frac{\pi k(m + \frac{1}{2})}{N} \bigg) \\
&=&\sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} x_m (-1)^{k}\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k(m + \frac{1}{2})}{N} \bigg) \\
  &=&(-1)^{k}\sqrt{\frac{2}{N}}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} x_m \cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k(m + \frac{1}{2})}{N} \bigg) \\
  &=& (-1)^k X_k
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Isn't a tilde missing in $x_k = x_{N-k-1}$?

Comment: I have tried to simplified some notations, hoping this is correct